# IntelliJ: Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, minecraft

I think I trying to solve this problem for any ways such as: CLASSPATH is wrong, Remove cache file , Restart.. etc...

**BUT One interesting issues**: I got fixed when I trying to add Libraries' New Java(such as spigot-1.17.1.jar) and Edit Modules Dependencies(Scope section) Normal Provided(*Maven: org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT*) -> Compile

[image]

Then this got fixed BUT I DON'T KNOW WHY THIS WORKING TO ME

**EXPLAIN:**

First of all, When I click(application menu) and press RUN button then I got this msg:

> Error: Could not find or load main class me.kennytool.betaplugin.BetaPluginHandler.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bukkit/event/Listener

[image]

```java
package me.kennytool.betaplugin;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;

public class BetaPluginHandler implements Listener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

        @EventHandler
        public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){

            Player player = e.getPlayer();

            if (player.hasPlayedBefore()){
                e.setJoinMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "[REJOIN]" + ": " + ChatColor.BOLD + player.getDisplayName() + ChatColor.YELLOW + " WELCOME BACK");
                // Have experienced logging log

            }else{
                e.setJoinMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "[FIRST]" + ": " + ChatColor.BOLD + player.getDisplayName() + ChatColor.BLUE + " WELCOME FIRST!");
                // First logging on!

            }

        }
    }
```

I don't know why this error shows to me.... Too many solution got it to solve this problems but this not WORK to me

**NOTE**: I used Java and with Minecraft Development Kit(Spigot)

**(This probs doesn't occur in plain Java Project)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshots, all the dependencies are marked as `scope` provided, this means that they are expected to be provided externally and not available on the classpath.  Please provide the contents of your pom.xml to verify, but I suspect you'll find a line on your dependencies that reads something like `<scope>provided</scope>` deleting this should resolve the issue.  You can read more about maven dependency scopes here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope

Comment: Ok I got solve this problems but has side-effect to delete <scope>provided</scope> format?
and Most of Scope changed Provided to Compile.

Comment: This is not a problem, you want your dependencies scoped as compile unless you plan on providing them yourself.  If you want to bundle the dependencies with your jar then you'll want to look into the maven assembly plugin and the configuration option of `jar-with-dependencies`.  Effectively, that will create a jar (when you run `mvn package`) with the dependency jars bundled with it.  There's a lot to maven and I strongly encourage you to read through its documentation.

Comment: yea I should read it But i have one more question
so if I set it to Provided then,  file size got smaller than compile? (Because API is built-in from an external container, it is excluded in the last packaging when designated as provisioned.)

Comment: It would be smaller because it won't contain the dependent jars.  If you'd like to see the differences, build the jars one with provided and one with compile scope and use `jar tvf <jar_file>` to view its contents, you'll see the differences.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciated with it I fixed it (application -> Include dependencies with "Provided" scope)